# Sort a list of lists in Python with different data types

Tags: python, sorting

My goal is to simply sort a list of lists with different types. The idea is to sort the first integer list and reorder the second list by the indices based on this new sorting. I've looked through many examples on stackoverflow already but none seem to solve the issue. Example and some of what I've tried:

```
test_list=[[1,2,5,1,7,4],['A','B','C','D','E','F']]
```

My Goal:

```
[[1,1,2,4,5,7],['A','D','B','F','C','E']]

#TRY 1
test_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0))
In [96]: test_list
Out[96]: [[1, 2, 5, 1, 7, 4], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']]

#TRY 2
In [97]: sorted(test_list,key=lambda x: x[0])
Out[97]: [[1, 2, 5, 1, 7, 4], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']]
```

One additional piece of information - if the data types are the same the above seems to work.

Comment: if you want a new list, `[sorted(sublist) for sublist in test_list]`. If you want in-place, `for sublist in test_list: sublist.sort()`

Comment: Presumably by not working you mean Python is telling you you can't compare dissimilar types (provide a [mcve] to save guessing). What would *you* expect for e.g. `'a' > 2`? In Python 3.x you need to be explicit about your expectation by writing it in your `key` function.

Comment: Wait, that *isn't* what you want. Can you try to specify *exactly* what you want? Do you want to sort the rest of the lists according to the the first sublist?

Comment: no. what the OP wants (tell me if i’m wrong) is to sort the first list, then sort the second list based on the new indices of the first list

Comment: @rassar right, I think we mean the same thing... not entirely sure...

Comment: @rassar - Yes, sort the first list and then arrange the second list by the indices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
zip(*sorted(zip(*test_list)))
```

Since this will produce tuples, you would have to do

```
map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(*test_list))))
# in Python 3 you also have to turn the map object into a list again
# list(map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(*test_list)))))
```

to get back your original lists.

What it does:

- [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the two lists
- sort the resulting pairs
- transpose them back

It will use the elements from the second list as tie-breakers since it sorts a list of pairs. If you want the sorting to be stable wrt the first list, you would have to you use a key function:

```
list(zip(*sorted(zip(*test_list), key=lambda t: t[0])))
```

Comment: Hmm, that's clever, but if two elements of the first tuple (from the inner `zip`) have the same value, it will sort the tuple lexicographically, wheras that might not be what the OP wnats.

Comment: for python 3 you'll have to force `zip` and `map` to `list` if they're the main caller to consume the iterator. "since this will produce tuples": no this will produce an iterator in python 3: `<zip object at 0x000000000326E708>` (hint: don't fix this for me, I already upvoted :))

Comment: This looks like it works. I'll accept when the time allows me to

Comment: In other words, try with `test_list=[[1,2,5,1,7,4],['D','B','C','A','E','F']]` and look at the difference between `list(zip(*sorted(zip(*test_list))))` and `list(zip(*sorted(zip(*test_list), key=lambda t:t[0])))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Updated my answer to include that nuance ;-)